# Mean time spent in each state per cluster - TramineR

Tags: r, dataframe, traminer

I would like to create a table (and not a plot) with the mean time spent in each state per cluster. Is there a way to do this with TramineR?

[image]

Comment: @Gilbert can you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean times for the set of sequences are provided by function `seqmeant`. Therefore, you could probably simply do

```
by(df_new_seq, cl.4fac, seqmeant)
```

And if you want the result in matrix form

```
res <- by(df_new_seq, cl.4fac, seqmeant)
mres <- matrix(unlist(res), nrow=nrow(res[[1]]), byrow=FALSE)
rownames(mres) <- rownames(res[[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution

```
seqmtplot(df_new.seq, group = cl1.4fac)
by(df_new.seq, cl1.4fac, seqistatd) ->a
```

Then I saved the values into a new data frame

```
 b<-a[["Type 8"]]
 b<-as.data.frame(b)
```

and I calculated the means

```
mean(b$Work)
```